# invoking business logic when property changes in struts 1.3

Tags: java, javabeans, struts-1

iam developing a web app in Struts and the problem is i want to invoke a business logic when one of the Action form bean property called "cashreceived" is updated(which is done by user) how to  use bound property(property listener) to solve it or happy if any other method suggested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i guess you must have provided textField on some dropdown box for changing property value.
Now such input components have onClick event on which you can write a javascript function to call.In that function write code for submitting form with the required action and method parameter.

use this javascript code :

```
function invokeLogic(){
document.yourFormName.action='somePath.do?method=someMethodWithLogic';
document.yourFormName.submit();
}

<input type="text" onblur="invokeLogic()"/>
```

Comment: can you help how to write server side script which updates values into table in server using javascript when the textfield value changes  -thanks for help :)